# How to choose row that met criteria if exist other wise randomly choose another?

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto

I have the following table:

```
article_id , locale, category_name, is_primary_local
  1             en              answers          True
  1             es              respuestas       False
  2             en              questions        False
  2             de              fragen           False
  2             it              domande          False
```

The key is `(article_id, locale)`

I want to create a table with `article_id` as key.
The logic is if there is primary local then use this for `category_name` If not choose one randomly. There can be only one primary_local per `article_id`.

so output can look like:

```
article_id , category_name
   1            answers
   2             fragen    -- or domande, questions
```

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
      article_id,
      MIN(CASE WHEN is_primary_local  Then category_name else ?????  END) as category_name
From table
GROUP BY article_id
```

But I don't know how to finish this case condition?

I'm using presto sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind instead of *choose one randomly* to return the minimum `category_name` then in your code use `COALESCE()` like this:

```
SELECT 
      article_id,
      COALESCE(
        MIN(CASE WHEN is_primary_local  THEN category_name END),
        MIN(category_name) 
      ) as category_name
From tablename
GROUP BY article_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following query:

```
select article_id, locale, category_name, is_primary_local
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() 
            over(partition by article_id order by is_primary_local desc, random()) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

The inner query ranks records within `article_id` groups, ordering by descending `is_primary_local` (this puts `true` value first), and then randomly. The outer query filters on the top record per group. As a bonus for using window functions, you can return all columns (not only `article_id` and `category_name`).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a17bd91a3a058ba27fd44394ef9f9133)**:

First execution:

```
article_id | locale | category_name | is_primary_local 
---------: | :----- | :------------ | :--------------- 
         1 | en     | answers       | t                
         2 | en     | questions     | f
```

Second execution:

```
article_id | locale | category_name | is_primary_local | rn
---------: | :----- | :------------ | :--------------- | -:
         1 | en     | answers       | t                |  1
         2 | de     | fragen        | f                |  1
```